# after installing gcc8.3.0, it seems that my program still use the default gcc dynamic link library(libstdc++.so.6) instead of my new gcc8.3.0 so

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, g++

in my centos7, I compiled gcc8.3.0 and installed it to the /usr/local/gcc8.3.0. the sub folder of it contains the higher version of dynamic link library such as libstdc++.so.6(it seems be make by libstdc++.so.6.0.25).

the /usr/local/gcc8.3.0 is not a defalut folder, so I made it the default gcc by add its subfolder "/bin" into the PATH of /etc/profile and then source /etc/profile.

I use the new gcc to compile a c++ program. but when I run the it, it reported an error like this：

```
./echo_server: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./echo_server)
./echo_server: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ./echo_server)
./echo_server: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./echo_server)
./echo_server: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./echo_server)
./echo_server: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/gflags/lib/libgflags.so.2)
./echo_server: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/gflags/lib/libgflags.so.2)
./echo_server: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/local/gflags/lib/libgflags.so.2)
./echo_server: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/local/gflags/lib/libgflags.so.2)
```

ok it seems that when runtime, the program will still find gcc so from default folder instead of the gcc folder which compiled it.

what should I do? just cp the /usr/local/gcc8.3.0/lib64 to /lib64? (Currently I do this, in order to be able to run the program), but it looks stupid..

find a reasonable solution to this problem

Comment: Why don't you just use [Red Hat Developer Toolset](https://developers.redhat.com/products/red-hat-developer-toolset/overview)?